# Windows 10 Creators Update for Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB (or LTSC)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, creators-update, windows-creators

How do I get the Windows 10 Creators Update for my operating system which is Windows 10 Enterprise 2016 LTSB?  I need this to get some BLE stuff working.  I have my BLE program working on my development machine which is Windows 10 Pro.

I've gone to the Updates tab on this computer and hit for Check for Updates and got "Your device is up to date".

I then tried going to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10 to do a manual update but it would not let me because I have "Enterprise" But it did state that there was a more recent version of Windows available (but not available through manual download because we have Enterprise).

I suspect there should be directories put down of the form C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\10.0.17134.0 once we install the Windows 10 Creator.

Thanks,

Dave